# Need only phone number from default contact

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm opening a default address book contact in my app, but it's opening all the detail of the contact. I only want the phone number, not the other details. How do I do this?

Below is the code I use.

```
ABPersonViewController *personController = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];

personController.personViewDelegate = self;
personController.allowsEditing = NO;

personController.displayedPerson = person;
personController.addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

personController.displayedProperties = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:           [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty],                                            nil];   

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:personController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I already give this answer please check this link

Click [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229901/how-to-get-contacts-in-to-our-native-application-from-addressbook/8519706#8519706)

Comment: actually i just want to show it in default address book, I dont have to display in manually. So for that we have to pass properties, but its not working.

Comment: In default address book of the iPhone there is no such option to display number instead of name. I think you have to try it manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
ABContact *contact = [collection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = contact.contactName;
cell.detailTextLabel.text=contact.phonenumbers;
```

i used abcontactshelper class for this.