# Populate UITableView with CFArray?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am getting all phone contacts in **CFArrayRef** from AddressBook using AddressBook framework.Now I want to populate **TableView** with that array of contacts.Is it possible to populate directly from CFArray to TableView or I should loop over CFArray into NSString one by one?

Comment: display output of this contact array ???? (NSLog)

Comment: I already NSlog each contact.But Now i want to show all contacts in UITableView.

Comment: @FarhanAli And what prevents you from it? I don't undesrtand your question. Why couldn't you?

Comment: @H2CO3: Is that any way that I pass CFArray directly to TableView without loop over it and with out convert each contact to NSString.

Comment: @FarhanAli Use `cell.textLabel.text = [(NSArray *)cfArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

CFArray is a Core Foundation Array. It is a C api to an array. CFArray is [toll-free-bridged](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Toll-FreeBridgin/Toll-FreeBridgin.html) to NSArray and can therefore be converted to NSArray by simply casting it. `NSArray *array = (NSArray *)cfArrayVariable`. When you use ARC you have to [bridge cast](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#bridged-casts) it to maintain the correct ownership.

Another solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3747877/1199344) by simply enumerating over the CFArray without casting.