# how to link to a contact page from a uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a very simple tableview of names (first and last).  They all correspond to a name in the device's address book. They also have the date that they were added. I'd like to add the functionality to click a name and send the user to the corresponding contact page.  So if they touched Jane Doe, it would take them to Jane Doe's contact page.  Is this doable?  If not, is there a way that I could at least get the contact's phone number and display it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Apple does not provide a public URL Scheme to deeplink into the contacts app (unfortunately) so there isn't an "Apple Supported" way to do so that I know of.  You can get contact information from the address book, you will need to set up and prompt your users of course.  See this SO question to get more information, or check the Apple Docs on this subject and report back with specific questions if you have them.  Happy Coding.

[SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747844/get-a-list-of-all-contacts-on-ios)

[Apple Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html)