# Remove unwanted characters, country code from phone numbers fetched from contacts iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7.1, ios6.0

How can i remove unwanted characters, country code  from phone numbers fetched from contacts  iOS.

[Fetch Contacts in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027118/fetch-contacts-in-ios-7)

I used the above SO link to fetch contacts. Am able to fetch all contacts. But my problem , am getting unwanted character in the phone numbers . How can i remove those unwanted characters from phone numbers in iOS 7 & iOS 6.

Please find contact detail added in Simulator

[image]

Please find the log in iOS 7 Simulator below:

```
2014-04-10 10:43:13.274 AddressBook[946:a0b] Contact name alan bold
2014-04-10 10:43:13.275 AddressBook[946:a0b] Phone number 1 (234) 567-89
2014-04-10 10:43:13.275 AddressBook[946:a0b] All numbers (
    "1\U00a0(234)\U00a0567-89"
)
2014-04-10 10:43:13.276 AddressBook[946:a0b] all contacts (
    "<ContactsData: 0x9984330>"
)
```

And Please find the log in iOS 6 Simulator below:

```
2014-04-10 10:37:44.965 AddressBook[883:c07] Fetching contact info ----> 
2014-04-10 10:37:44.973 AddressBook[883:c07] Contact name alsn vols
2014-04-10 10:37:44.974 AddressBook[883:c07] Phone number 1 (234) 567-890
2014-04-10 10:37:44.974 AddressBook[883:c07] All numbers (
    "1 (234) 567-890"
)
2014-04-10 10:37:44.975 AddressBook[883:c07] all contacts (
    "<ContactsData: 0x7c56510>"
)
```

And guide me how to remove country code from phone numbers

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129521/remove-all-but-numbers-from-nsstring.

Comment: Are you just trying to remove non numeric characters from a string?

Comment: Yes am trying to remove non numeric characters from string which is a phone number

Comment: Classic problem with many solutions.

Comment: Give me one solution @CrimsonChris

Comment: @apple post your link as an answer.

Comment: The phone that you see in the address book is a representation of the phone number. For the same phone number (for example +123456789), you will see for the US locale 1 (234) 567-89 and for the Spanish locale +1 23 456 789 (without parenthesis). When you get the contact phone you will have + or white spaces at most

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Google's libPhoneNumber library](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) to extract the phone number from the contact and normalize it in several formats (Local format, International format and E164 format).

I suggest you to give it a try :)