# ios edit phone number in contact programmatically

Tags: ios, edit, contacts

I want to read contact list and edit all phone numbers.
For example , find all number by prefix (511) and change it by (513).
For read all contacts, I find this code (and it works fine):

[Fetch Contacts in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027118/fetch-contacts-in-ios-7)

But for edit contact , I couldn't find anything.
Can any one help me? Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, you are not allowed to edit contacts, let alone *batch* edit contacts.

Comment: @duci9y is right. The only way I could handle updates, was to find the old contact, delete it, and insert a new one to the address book.

Comment: Of course you can edit contacts. Do a search. There are plenty of existing topics showing how.

Comment: Yes you can edit the contact.

Comment: I retract from my previous comment. Just tried, and it works. Will post some sample code as soon as I can.

Comment: Just one question. How are you deciding which contacts to edit? I mean, you only plan to edit numbers that have been inserted by **you**, because editing ALL contacts in the address book is wrong. Do you insert contacts in a specific address group (`ABGroup`) or keep a list of inserted contacts with their record id (`ABRecord`)?

Comment: one problem! This top answer remove added phone numbers. And only save last number in contacts for me!And not solved my problem.