# MFMailComposeViewController get email "From:" and send email on background

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

[image]

Hi,

I have an app that has a feature to send email. I have success do that by using MFMailComposeViewController. For next requirement, I have 2 questions here:

1. How can i get "email list from" (that showed in dropdown, tesmojones2@gmail.com & tesmojones3@gmail.com) in Objective-C.
2. Can i send email via background? without showing MFMailComposeViewController.

Comment: 1. I'm not sure if this is what you mean and I haven't tried it out: [UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:tesmojones2@gmail.com,tesmojones3@gmail.com]]. 2. As far as I know, no you cannot; not without writing all of the stuff you get for free with MFMailComposeViewController out yourself.

Comment: You cannot send an email without the user seeing the MFMailComposerViewController. As for question #1, [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19027204/312312)