# How to create a contact picker in Xcode for iOS application?

Tags: objective-c, ios8

I'm creating an app that needs phone numbers to be typed or selected from the contacts. I wanna know that how to do this. How to allow user to select a contact's phone number from the contacts list? (Something Like Messages App)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the contacts list using AddressBook framework in ios, and get the details you wanted from  the list of contacts.
Refer the answer for this question: [Fetch Contacts in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027118/fetch-contacts-in-ios-7)

Answer (score 0):

I've just commit [LGPhoneBook](https://github.com/DavidSahakyan/LGPhoneBook)

You need to call

```
[[LGPhonebook sharedInstance] readContactsWithCallbackHandler:^(NSArray *contacts) {
      for (PhoneBookContact *contact in contacts) {
           NSLog(@"Name: %@, mobile: %@", contact.name, contact.mobile);
      }
}];
```