# How to import contacts into my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, contacts

I need to access the contacts of my iPhone into  my app.

I am using **Xcode 7.2** and **IOS-9**.
Give me best framework or library which is usefully for me.

I try to work on the **ABAddressbook framework** but it has been deprecated.

Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747844/get-a-list-of-all-contacts-on-ios

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch Contacts in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027118/fetch-contacts-in-ios-7)

Comment: You can use Contacts and Contacts UI frameworks instead of ABAddressbook framework Read Deprecated APIs in [iOS 9.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple has introduced new frameworks Contacts and ContactsUI for accessing contacts for iOS9 and above.

The previous ABAddressbook framework has been deprecated. You might find a lot of info in SO on this.

You can make use of  [ContactsUI](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactsUI/Reference/CNContactPickerViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016091-CH1-SW1) framework for iOS9+ devices

```
- (void) presentContacts
{
    CNContactPickerViewController *contactPicker = [[CNContactPickerViewController alloc] init];
    contactPicker.delegate = self;
    [_myViewController presentViewController:contactPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

//Listen for delegates
 - (void) contactPickerDidCancel: (CNContactPickerViewController *) picker
{
    NSLog(@"didCancel");
}

- (void) contactPicker: (CNContactPickerViewController *) picker
      didSelectContact: (CNContact *)                     contact
{
    NSLog(@"didSelectContact"):
}


- (void)      contactPicker: (CNContactPickerViewController *) picker
   didSelectContactProperty: (CNContactProperty *)             contactProperty
{
    NSLog(@"didSelectProperty");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- CNContactPickerViewController

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactsUI/Reference/CNContactPickerViewController_Class/

- Address book ui framework

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/AddressBookUI_Framework/index.html

- MFMessageComposeViewController https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/
- tutorials http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-import-contact-address-book/
- http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.in/2012/02/how-to-import-contacts-from-address.html