# Import ios contacts in a tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, ios7

I searched the internet for importing `iOS` contacts in a `UITableViewController` because I have a `UITableViewController` as a root for a `UINavigationController` and I called it contacts like `whatsapp` does and what I have found is how to import the contacts picker with a modal segue and I dont want that I want to import them in a custom cell and edit on them . So how can I do that ?

Comment: but only load array of contact in tableview simple.

Comment: can u tell me how can I make this function echo out fontacts in cells

Comment: @user3380361 you getting contact array from this function and load that array in tableview . but you know how to show data in tableview ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a list of all contacts on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747844/get-a-list-of-all-contacts-on-ios)

Comment: @user3380361 check this link http://iphoneappcode.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-create-uitableview-in-ios-sdk.html

Comment: @user3380361 and also check this link demo in last option for download  http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/07/26/iphone-programming-tutorial-hello-world/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function this is working for me.

```
 -(NSArray *)getAllContacts
{

    CFErrorRef *error = nil;


    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);

    __block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
    if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) { // we're on iOS 6
        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            accessGranted = granted;
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        });
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    }
    else { // we're on iOS 5 or older
        accessGranted = YES;
    }

    if (accessGranted) {

#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"Fetching contact info ----> ");
#endif


        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
        ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
        CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName);
        CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
        NSMutableArray* items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:nPeople];


        for (int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++)
        {
            ContactsData *contacts = [ContactsData new];

            ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);

            //get First Name and Last Name

            contacts.firstNames = (__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

            contacts.lastNames =  (__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

            if (!contacts.firstNames) {
                contacts.firstNames = @"";
            }
            if (!contacts.lastNames) {
                contacts.lastNames = @"";
            }

            // get contacts picture, if pic doesn't exists, show standart one

            NSData  *imgData = (__bridge NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
            contacts.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
            if (!contacts.image) {
                contacts.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NOIMG.png"];
            }
            //get Phone Numbers

            NSMutableArray *phoneNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            ABMultiValueRef multiPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
            if (ABMultiValueGetCount(multiPhones)<0)
            {
                contacts.phonenumber=@"";
            }
            for(CFIndex i=0;i<ABMultiValueGetCount(multiPhones);i++) {

                CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiPhones, i);
                NSString *phoneNumber = (__bridge NSString *) phoneNumberRef;
                contacts.phonenumber=phoneNumber;
                [phoneNumbers addObject:phoneNumber];

                NSLog(@"All numbers %@", phoneNumbers);

            }


            [contacts setNumbers:phoneNumbers];

            //get Contact email

            NSMutableArray *contactEmails = [NSMutableArray new];
            ABMultiValueRef multiEmails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);

            for (CFIndex i=0; i<ABMultiValueGetCount(multiEmails); i++) {
                CFStringRef contactEmailRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiEmails, i);
                NSString *contactEmail = (__bridge NSString *)contactEmailRef;

                [contactEmails addObject:contactEmail];
                // NSLog(@"All emails are:%@", contactEmails);

            }

            [contacts setEmails:contactEmails];



            [items addObject:contacts];

            [Contactarray addObject:contacts];

#ifdef DEBUG
            NSLog(@"Person is: %@", contacts.firstNames);
            //            NSLog(@"Phones are: %@", contacts.numbers);
            //            NSLog(@"Email is:%@", contacts.emails);
#endif




        }
        NSLog(@"%@",items);
        return items;



    } else {
#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"Cannot fetch Contacts :( ");
#endif
        return NO;


    }

}
```

i hope this code useful for you .

Comment: thanks alot for your reply ... but i have a question can you post for me how the whole TableViewController will be ?