# Getting array of user's contacts in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, abaddressbook

I've written the following code for getting a user's contacts with CNContact module in iOS9. What would the equivalent code be for iOS8, as I realize that the Contact module is a new addition for iOS9

```
CNAuthorizationStatus status = [CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts];
if (status == CNAuthorizationStatusDenied || status == CNAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"This app previously was refused permissions to contacts; Please go to settings and grant permission to this app so it can use contacts" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:TRUE completion:nil];
    return;
}

CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    // make sure the user granted us access

    if (!granted) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        });
        return;
    }

    // build array of contacts
    NSMutableArray *contacts = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSError *fetchError;
    CNContactFetchRequest *request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:@[CNContactIdentifierKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, [CNContactFormatter descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle:CNContactFormatterStyleFullName]]];

    BOOL success = [store enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError usingBlock:^(CNContact *contact, BOOL *stop) {
        [contacts addObject:contact];
    }];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"error = %@", fetchError);
    }

    //save array of fetched contacts
    self.contacts = contacts;

}];
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ABAddressBook`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/index.html) Class.

Sample code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3747877/2710486)