# Fetching Contacts from mobile and store to sqliteDB using Swift 3

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift3, cncontact

I am new in the Swift 3 language and I want to fetch contacts from the phone in an array and then store in sqliteDB. Please help.

I saw an old tutorial of Swift 2.1 but all these methods are deprecated and I tried a lot with `CNContacts` but this was not helpful for me.

I also tried this link of Stack Overflow but did not get any help:
[Fetching all contacts in ios Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973574/fetching-all-contacts-in-ios-swift)

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried already until then ?

Comment: Sorry I undo whole my code because it was not working.

Comment: Do you really want to store your contacts in a sqlite DB ? You have some great alternatives. I usually go with [Realm](https://realm.io/) but you could also use [CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html?utm_source=iosstash.io)
And to fetch the contacts, please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34095632/3844377)

Comment: it does not matter where I have to store data. my main focus is to retrieve  contacts .

Comment: may be I will go with coredata

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34095632/3844377) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just been working on a similar problem so i'll give you my code. I put it together from a few different threads I found (including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669612/how-to-fetch-all-contacts-record-in-ios-9-using-contacts-framework/34095632#34095632)). Our requirement is to just get the phone number alone from all contacts and put it into a String array but you could easily modify this to do more:

```
func getContacts(){

    contactStore.requestAccess(for: .contacts, completionHandler: {
        granted, error in

        var contacts: [CNContact] = {
            let contactStore = CNContactStore()

            //Change keys here to retreive more than just the phone number of the contact
            let keysToFetch = [CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]

            // Get all the containers
            var allContainers: [CNContainer] = []
            do {
                allContainers = try contactStore.containers(matching: nil)
            } catch {
                print("Error fetching containers")
            }

            var results: [CNContact] = []

            // Iterate all containers and append their contacts to our results array
            for container in allContainers {

                let fetchPredicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsInContainer(withIdentifier: container.identifier)

                do {

                    let containerResults = try contactStore.unifiedContacts(matching: fetchPredicate, keysToFetch: keysToFetch as [CNKeyDescriptor])

                    results.append(contentsOf: containerResults)

                    for phone in results{

                        for labeledValue in phone.phoneNumbers{
                            self.phoneNumbersArray.append(labeledValue.value.stringValue)
                        }
                    }

                } catch {
                    print("Error fetching results for container")
                }
            }

            return results
        }()

        self.getFriendsFromPhoneNumbers()
    })
}
```

This goes through all the containers and returns an array of CNObjects (with only the phone numbers inside but you can make it get more by just changing the keys) and then iterates through each Contact and label inside the array to insert just the phone numbers as Strings into a Phone Number array.

Comment: it works for me. but what should I write to fetch firstName and familyName?

Comment: You have to use more keys like: [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey]

Comment: I already changed the key but what I have to write in this for loop 


///////////////////////
for labeledValue in phone.phoneNumbers{
                                print(labeledValue.value.stringValue)
                            }

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts/cncontact) you can use the Name Properties to get those from the objects inside the results array.

Comment: Okay let me properly check all these Keys. thanks alot