# iOS Fetch only contacts having email address

Tags: ios, swift

I can't find a proper reference to Contacts framework by Apple, so I'm struggling with this problem, I need to fill the TableView with contacts having at least one email address, ContactsPickerController is not the solution, I need tableview to be filled right at `viewDidLoad()`. Can anyone please provide a solution for my problem.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973574/fetching-all-contacts-in-ios-swift

Comment: Fetch them all. Then display only the ones with email addresses.

Answer (score -2):

You can get contact like this:

***Reference*** -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/37388443/7512091

```
var contacts = [CNContact]()
let keys = [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle(.FullName)]
let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys)

do {
    try self.contactStore.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(request) {             
        (contact, stop) in
        // Array containing all unified contacts from everywhere
        contacts.append(contact)
    }
} 
catch {
    print("unable to fetch contacts")
}
```

This `contact` object's type is `CNContact` and it has a `emailAddresses` property which is an array of labeled email addresses for the contact.

***Apple Reference:*** -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontact?language=objc