# I want to fetch contact list from phone on tableview in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, addressbook

I have written this code

contactlistvc.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ContactListVc : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    UITableView *contactTable;
    NSMutableArray *tableData;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *contactTable;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tableData;
```

contactlistvc.m

```
#import "ContactListVc.h"
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import "Person.h"

@interface ContactListVc ()

@end

@implementation ContactListVc
@synthesize tableData,contactTable;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    contactTable = [[UITableView alloc]init];
    contactTable.dataSource = self;
    contactTable.delegate = self;
    [self getPersonOutOfAddressBook];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Identifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    Person *person = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = person.fullName;


    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)getPersonOutOfAddressBook
{
    //1
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

    if (addressBook != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Succesful.");
        NSLog(@"tabledata %@",tableData);

        //2
        NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

        //3
        NSUInteger i = 0; for (i = 0; i < [allContacts count]; i++)
        {
            Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
            ABRecordRef contactPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[i];

            //4
            NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson,
                                                                                  kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
            NSString *lastName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
            NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];

            person.firstName = firstName; person.lastName = lastName;
            person.fullName = fullName;

            //email
            //5
            ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonEmailProperty);

            //6
            NSUInteger j = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(emails); j++) {
                NSString *email = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, j);
                if (j == 0) {
                    person.homeEmail = email;
                    NSLog(@"person.homeEmail = %@ ", person.homeEmail);
                }
                else if (j==1) person.workEmail = email;
            }

            //7
            [self.tableData addObject:person];
        }

        //8
        CFRelease(addressBook);
    } else {
        //9
        NSLog(@"Error reading Address Book");
    }
}
```

But i am not getting the contact list. only successfull is coming on console window. I am having 3 tab bar on one tab of contact i want to show the contact list of phone in tableview. Plz help me , thanks.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i6bymuddrwxbmkp/AddressBook.zip?dl=0

Comment: you can all details in array format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a list of all contacts on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747844/get-a-list-of-all-contacts-on-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to first get permission to access the native DB...**

```
- (void)requestPermissionForContactsAccessAndFetch
{

ABAuthorizationStatus status = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus();

    if (status != kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized && status != kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
    // tell user to enable contacts in privacy settings
        NSLog(@"You previously denied access: You must enable access to contacts in settings");

        return;
    }

    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);
    if (!addressBook) {
        NSLog(@"ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions error: %@", CFBridgingRelease(error));
        return;
    }

    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
       if (error) {
        NSLog(@"ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion error: %@", CFBridgingRelease(error));
    }

    if (granted) {
        [self getContactsFromAddressBook:addressBook];
    } else {
        // tell user to enable contacts in privacy settings
        NSLog(@"You just denied access: You must enable access to contacts in settings");
    }

    CFRelease(addressBook);
});
}
```

**Then you can get all contacts in an array...**

```
- (NSMutableArray*)getContactsFromAddressBook:(ABAddressBookRef)addressBook
   {
NSArray *allData = CFBridgingRelease(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook));
    NSInteger contactCount = [allData count];

for (int i = 0; i < contactCount; i++) {
    ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex((__bridge CFArrayRef)allData, i);

    NSString *firstName = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
    NSString *lastName  = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty));

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    if (firstName) {
        dictionary[@"firstName"] = firstName;
    }
    if (lastName) {
        dictionary[@"lastName"]  = lastName;
    }

    ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    CFIndex phoneNumberCount = ABMultiValueGetCount(phones);

    if (phoneNumberCount > 0) {
        NSString *phone = CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, 0));
        dictionary[@"phone"] = phone;
    }

    // or if you wanted to iterate through all of them, you could do something like this...        
    // for (int j = 0; j < phoneNumberCount; j++) {
    //      NSString *phone = CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j));
     // }

    if (phones) {
        CFRelease(phones);
    }

    [arrOfContacts addObject:dictionary];
}
}
```